# How to set data from JSON in Calendario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, plugins

I've recently downloaded the Calendario jQuery plugin from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/27/calendario-a-flexible-calendar-plugin/

It works well, and the example in the index.html says that I can set up events in the calendar like this:

```
cal.setData({
    '03-01-2013' : '<a href="#">testing</a>',
    '03-10-2013' : '<a href="#">testing</a>',
    '03-12-2013' : '<a href="#">testing</a>'
});
```

There's no problem, the tests are show up in the calendar, and I can click on any of these. I want to set up a simple database for the events in the calendar, to make it easier to store and handle, and I need to create a simple UI for the plugin.

I have this javascript (jQuery) function on my page:

```
var dates = {};
$.post('ajax.php?getdates').done(function(r){
    alert(r);
    dates = $.parseJSON(r);
    alert(dates);
});
cal.setData( dates );
```

I have the database with some test datas, but when I pass it to the plugin via an AJAX request, it doesn't show up in the calendar.

You can view the page here: http://hafehungarykft.tarhelykeszito.hu/naptar/?nologin

And the AJAX page here: http://hafehungarykft.tarhelykeszito.hu/naptar/ajax.php?getdates&nologin

You can access the pages with the nologin flag for testing purposes. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now realized that the dates was in the wrong format. I used YYYY-MM-DD instead of the preferred MM-DD-YYYY. It was a painful mistake taking days to solve, simply because of my inattention...